# How do I properly perform modulus operations in Batch?

Tags: math, windows-7, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that performs operations depending on the result of a modulus operation performed on a set variable.  However, I can't seem to get it quite right.

To first of all test my syntax for the mathematical operation, I've been trying to get a simpler script to produce desired results.

```
:START
SETLOCAL
SET /P Input-Num="Input Number: "
SET /A Input-Num=%Input-Num% %% 2
ECHO %Input-Num%
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE 
:END
```

If I input `5`, the expected output is `1`.  However, instead I get a message saying `Missing operator.` and then it outputs `5`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this DOS or something else?  I get `1` with no `Missing operator` when I run that exact sample (with `@ECHO OFF` added at the top)

Comment: Your code works fine when from from a batch file. If you are typing it directly into CMD then don't escape the `%`. use `%` instead of `%%`.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables First off, I love your screen name.  It's in CMD on Windows 7.  I've updated the tags.

Comment: @vcsjones I'll try it again, but I've been running it as a batch file the whole time.  Perhaps the only significant difference is I've been using `SET /P` for the first variable setting.

Comment: Updated question to reflect `SET /P`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `SET /P` is your problem, as 5 is no longer treated as a numerical value.  Your example as above works as expected

Comment: Is there a way to use `SET /P` (or something that would operate similarly) *and* perform math operations on the variable?

Comment: See this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/684389/334849.  They use `SET /P`, then do `SET /A` for a second variable later in the code.

Comment: Tried that now.  Still doesn't work.  Now I get *two* `Missing operator` errors.

Comment: Already did.  I figured it out now.  Apparently, having dashes in variable names (yeah, I was using different variable names) doesn't mix well with performing math on those variables.  (Edited those in now, too.)

Comment: NOTE: I pulled extra variable and set it up to work directly with the input, and it works now that I've removed the dashes from the variable names.