# If i type the wrong number or letter on batch how do i make it loop? BATCH

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
cls
:menu
echo 1. Start
echo 2. Info
set /p select=Enter Number:

if not defined select (
cls
goto loop
)

if %select% == 1 goto start
if %select% == 2 goto info
```

Comment: Same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688367/batch-text-based-game-bugs-when-the-player-doesnt-provide-the-correct-input)?

Answer (score 0):

Almost done. You have tested any valid value. All `if` have failed. You have a label (`:menu`) where to jump Add `goto menu` at the end of your code. And change your `goto loop` to `goto menu`

Answer (score -1):

I would much rather have my code more compact by doing this and it WORKS alot better!

```
@echo off
cls
:menu
echo 1. Start
echo 2. Info
set /p select=Enter Number:  
if "%select%" == "1" goto start
if "%select%" == "2" goto info
goto menu
```

What it's doing is checking to see if ones true, if it's not it'll go to see if 2 is true, if not it'll goto the next line of code which is goto menu which will just go straight to menu, Unless you want to display undefined do something like this:

```
:menu
@echo off
cls
echo 1. Start
echo 2. Info
set /p select=Enter Number:  
if %select% == 1 goto start
if %select% == 2 goto info
goto undefined
:undefined
echo Undefined!
pause
goto menu
```

Comment: `if "%select%" == "1" goto :start` <-- use double quotes like this to protect the batch file from null input and two words and poison characters.  Then your top suggestion is very good.