# Why is 2 times [0-9] better than once?

Tags: regex, batch-file

Question
[Batch File input validation - Make sure user entered an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2516095/1417694)
, has this answer:

> You can also use a quite simple trick:
>
> `echo %userinput%|findstr /r /c:"^[0-9][0-9]*$" >nul`
>
> `if errorlevel 1 (echo not a number) else (echo number)`
>
> This uses findstr's regular expression matching capabilities. They aren't very impressive but useful at times.

My question - why is `[0-9]` written twice?

Comment: Because otherwise it would match an empty string.

Comment: @trincot `findstr` doesn't support `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing in a command prompt window `findstr /?` outputs the help for this command.

The search regular expression means:

- `^` ... find a string at begin of a line
- `[0-9]` ... which has at least 1 digit
- `[0-9]*` ... and can have **0 or more** digits
- `$` ... and ends at end of the line.

In other words the line output by **ECHO** must have 1 or more digits and no other character for a positive match with exit code `0` assigned to environment variable `ERRORLEVEL`. Any other string on output line results in no match and exit code `1`.

The first `[0-9]` is needed to make sure the user input consists of at least 1 digit. Otherwise an empty line would result also in a positive match. **FINDSTR** does not support multiplier `+` which in other applications with regular expression support means **1 or more** of previous character or character class or expression.

Well, a not defined `userinput` would result in output `ECHO is OFF` or `ECHO is ON` to process by **FINDSTR** if `userinput` was not defined before `set /P "userinput=prompt text: "` and the user just hits <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. For that reason `^[0-9]*$` would work here also by chance because it does not occur here that **FINDSTR** has to process an empty line.

But **FINDSTR** has some unexpected matching behavior. For example `[0-9]` matches also `¹` and `²` and `³` depending on code page like Windows-1252, see [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/) Therefore it would be better to use as validation regular expression:

```
^[0123456789][0123456789]*$
```

That expression looks not as compact as `^[0-9][0-9]*$` but is better for user input validation.

Please note that even when the user input passes this test, the entered number string could be invalid for further processing in an arithmetic expression, for example if the user enters `45829413953053`. This number is too large for a 32-bit signed integer supporting only numbers in the range `-2147483648` to `2147483647`.